# How do I get rid of jenv in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, command-line-interface, jenv

I think I need to undo some commands I entered when trying to get jenv on my ubuntu instance and I am not sure how to do that.

Here's what I did:

`brew install jenv`

`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`

That last command gave me an error, and I ended up restarting my shell for whatever reason. Since then, all text is white (used to be multicolored), brew no longer works, and it says this:

> Command 'jenv' not found, did you mean:

> command 'env' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)

> Try: sudo apt install

> Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.
> user@DESKTOP-FG073RE:/mnt/c/Users/user$

I fear I messed up the PATH but I am not sure how to fix it. I tried to run the same command again but omitting the 'j' but that did nothing. Can't seem to find anything about this error online either. I also tried to uninstall jenv but that also did nothing.

Comment: so you remove the `export PATH="../henf/bin:$PATH"` line and everything that follows from `~/.bash_profile`, and log back in.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I went into the ~/.bash_profile I made and deleted everything from it

Comment: deleting everything might help but it may cause other issues as it contains other stuff that other applications /user needs. I don't recommend this option